# iPod touch 4th gen restore broken

Tags: ios

So the device is jailbroken, and I'm trying to sell it so I'd like to update and wipe it. It works perfectly, all my apps, music, videos, etc. are on the device, and even after trying to flash it clean, restore from itunes, etc. the device still boots up just fine when I try and use it. It's the strangest thing.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what your question really is. Can you add some information about what you are trying to do and where/how it fails?

Comment: It's relatively easy to infer the they're trying to wipe the device clean, and for some reason that's not happening. Jonathan latched onto magic words [in his answer below](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/69937/1346) that the OP included, those being "restore from iTunes". The question is poorly worded, and difficult to get the details, but not unclear.

Comment: What exactly are trying to do to wipe the device?

Answer (score 1):

When you perform the reset, do not "restore from backup", as iTunes will prompt you to do when it detects the "empty" device.  Instead, press cancel, and your iPod Touch should be empty.

For the most security, you should perform the erase from the device itself - In Settings, go to General, and select Reset; then, select "Erase All Content and Settings".  It may take a while, but it is a secure way to erase the device.

Comment: How long would it take? I let it go for several hours once, but the progress bar never changed, and if I soft reset it, it worked fine, as if nothing ever happened. I'm also not restoring from a backup, I tried restoring from both a 6.0 image, and a 5.0.1 image, both failes

Comment: It can take many hours.  You didn't mention any failure in your post - do you get an error message?

Comment: they seem to be very random, ranging from unknown error 11, to 1600, to 1611,1614, and one in the 3000, I think I may have fixed it, ironically using redsn0w's advanced features